# Swift Calendar, Weekday starting on Monday instead Sunday

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

Guys I'm following a tutorial to show a calendar in my app using SwiftUI

Everything works but I need:
show the names of the week from Monday and not from Sunday
and change that days based on the first day of the week

For now I have done this, how can I achieve my goals?

```
private extension Calendar {
    
        func generateDates(for interval: DateInterval, matching components: DateComponents) -> [Date] {
            var dates = [interval.start]
            enumerateDates(startingAfter: interval.start, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime) { result, _, stop in
                guard let date = result else { return }
                guard date < interval.end else {
                    stop = true
                    return
                }
                dates.append(date)
            }
            return dates
        }
        
        func generateDays(for interval: DateInterval) -> [Date] {
            generateDates(for: interval, matching: dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: interval.start))
        }
    }
```

```
    func makeDays() -> [Date] {
            guard let firstWeek = calendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfMonth, for: selectedDate),
                  let lastWeek = calendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfMonth, for: firstWeek.end - 1) else { return [] }
            let interval = DateInterval(start: firstWeek.start, end: lastWeek.end)
            return calendar.generateDays(for: interval)
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what is your goal. If you run your method today what should be the result? Be more specific. Does the time make any difference? Or do you want a time insensitive result?

Comment: @LeoDabus I was referring to the names of the days of the week. But apparently I solved as the days of the week are automatically translated and positioned correctly (Monday to Sunday and not Sunday to Saturday) when using Locale (identifier: "it") when using DateFormatter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a custom Gregorian calendar and set the first weekday to Monday

```
var customCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
customCalendar.firstWeekday = 2
```

Comment: this is great. Do you know if there is a calendar API to check the preferred start of week for a given locale? Some regions use Monday some use Sunday as the start of the week.

Answer (score -2):

Create a list and alternate the numbers of the week:

```swift
return [0,7,1,2,3,4,5,6][Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date())]
// Monday -> 1
// ...
// Sunday -> 7
```